# Multiple parameters in a function in Powershell. Reduction of repeating code fragment

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with writing a function for my PS script.
I have seen a lot of topics with very similar titles but was never able to apply them in my case.

I have a simple script that gathers logs from the common source and places them in separate folders/archives. It was shorter in the beginning but now after storage change, it became a bit silly.

Could someone maybe help me to understand how I can reduce this code to one function? It should work silently on a daily basis without any input.

BR and thanks in advance

```
$Date = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

#$Date = "2021-02-28"

$PathFailedEU = 'P:\IntegrationFileShare\failed\europe'
$PathLogsEU = 'P:\IntegrationFileShare\logs\europe'

$PathFailedAPAC = 'P:\IntegrationFileShare\failed\apac'
$PathLogsAPAC = 'P:\IntegrationFileShare\logs\apac'

$PathFailedLATAM = 'P:\IntegrationFileShare\failed\latam'
$PathLogsLATAM = 'P:\IntegrationFileShare\logs\latam'

#$Dest = 'C:\tmp\SCRPT\'
$DestEU = 'C:\tmp\SCRPT\europe\'
$DestAPAC = 'C:\tmp\SCRPT\apac\'
$DestLATAM = 'C:\tmp\SCRPT\latam\'

$compress_EU_log = @{
Path = $DestEU + '*.log' 
CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
DestinationPath = ($DestEU + 'Logs_EU_' + ($Date) + '.zip')
}
$compress_EU_failed = @{
Path = $DestEU + '*.log'
CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
DestinationPath = ($DestEU + 'Failed_EU_' + ($Date) + '.zip')
}
$compress_APAC_log = @{
Path = $DestAPAC + '*.log'
CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
DestinationPath = ($DestAPAC + 'Logs_APAC_' + ($Date) + '.zip')
}
$compress_APAC_failed = @{
Path = $DestAPAC + '*.log'
CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
DestinationPath = ($DestAPAC + 'Failed_APAC_' + ($Date) + '.zip')
}
$compress_LATAM_log = @{
Path = $DestLATAM + '*.log'
CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
DestinationPath = ($DestLATAM + 'Logs_LATAM_' + ($Date) + '.zip')
}
$compress_LATAM_failed = @{
Path = $DestLATAM + '*.log'
CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
DestinationPath = ($DestLATAM + 'Failed_LATAM_' + ($Date) + '.zip')
}

gci -path $PathLogsEU -filter *$Date* -recurse | %{cp $_.pspath -destination $DestEU}
if(Test-Path $compress_EU_log.Path){Compress-Archive @compress_EU_log}
Remove-Item -Path $DestEU* -Include *.log

gci -path $PathFailedEU -filter *$Date* -recurse | %{cp $_.pspath -destination $DestEU}
if(Test-Path $compress_EU_failed.Path){Compress-Archive @compress_EU_failed}
Remove-Item -Path $DestEU* -Include *.log

gci -path $PathLogsAPAC -filter *$Date* -recurse | %{cp $_.pspath -destination $DestAPAC}
if(Test-Path $compress_APAC_log.Path){Compress-Archive @compress_APAC_log}
Remove-Item -Path $DestAPAC* -Include *.log

gci -path $PathFailedAPAC -filter *$Date* -recurse | %{cp $_.pspath -destination $DestAPAC}
if(Test-Path $compress_APAC_failed){Compress-Archive @compress_APAC_failed}
Remove-Item -Path $DestAPAC* -Include *.log

gci -path $PathLogsLATAM -filter *$Date* -recurse | %{cp $_.pspath -destination $DestLATAM}
if(Test-Path $compress_LATAM_log.Path){Compress-Archive @compress_LATAM_log}
Remove-Item -Path $DestLATAM* -Include *.log

gci -path $PathFailedLATAM -filter *$Date* -recurse | %{cp $_.pspath -destination $DestLATAM}
if(Test-Path $compress_LATAM_failed.Path){Compress-Archive @compress_LATAM_failed}
Remove-Item -Path $DestLATAM* -Include *.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sergii,

Basically, you want to look for things that are being repeated and what differences they have. Then you turn the differences into parameters for your function and then use those parameters to substitute in the statements.

In your case the differences are the areas, so you setup that as your parameter then eliminate all reference to the region in the code and replace it where necessary with the parameter $Area.

```
Function Process-Logs {

  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
     [string] $Area
  )

  $PathFailed  = "P:\IntegrationFileShare\failed\$Area"
  $PathLogs    = "P:\IntegrationFileShare\logs\$Area"
  
  #$Dest = "C:\tmp\SCRPT\"
  $Dest = "C:\tmp\SCRPT\$Area\"
  
  $compress_log = @{
    Path             = $Dest + "*.log" 
    CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
    DestinationPath  = ($Dest + "Logs_$Area_" + ($Date) + ".zip")
  }
  $compress_failed = @{
    Path             = $Dest + "*.log"
    CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
    DestinationPath  = ($Dest + "Failed_$Area_" + ($Date) + ".zip")
  }
  
  gci -path $PathLogs -filter *$Date* -recurse | 
    %{cp $_.pspath -destination $Dest}
  if(Test-Path $compress_log.Path) {Compress-Archive @compress_log}
  Remove-Item -Path $Dest* -Include *.log
  
  gci -path $PathFailed -filter *$Date* -recurse | 
    %{cp $_.pspath -destination $Dest}
  if(Test-Path $compress_failed.Path) {Compress-Archive @compress_failed}
  Remove-Item -Path $Dest* -Include *.log

} #End Process-Logs
```

Now you do have one problem as you have an inconsistency with "europe" where you use it in some commands and then use "EU" in others. You need to standardize for good functioning of the function. Use either "europe" or "EU" but be consistent.

You would call the function like this:

```
$Date = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
Process-Logs -Area "Europe"
Process-Logs -Area "LATAM"
Process-Logs -Area "APAC"
```

Of course you could put those areas in an array and then use a for each loop to process them.

Also, I'd suggest that you space your code out to make it easier to read. Remember you can break a line on any character that is always followed by more code (+,-,{,(,|,) and operators (-and, -not, -like, -eq, etc.)

HTH

Comment: Ohh wow. Now I know more.
Thank you for the help.